# Creating a LINQ Expression that goes over more tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Well I am having problems building a Linq Expression I will now explain the Problem

I have 4 Tables (Models) which look like this in a very simple way:

> **Users**
>
> UserID (PK)
>
> Username (string,
>   NOT NULL)

> **UserInEvent**
>
> UserInEventID (PK)
>
> UserID
>   (FK, NOT NULL)
>
> EventID (FK, NOT NULL)

> **Event**
>
> EventID (PK)
>
> EventName (string,
>   NOT NULL)

> **UserInTraining**
>
> UserInTrainingID (PK)
>
> UserID (FK, NULL)
>
> EventID (FK, NOT NULL)
>
> Username (string,
>   NOT NULL)

**Now some stuff that you should know:**

- Registered Users can be added to a Event (UserInEvent) and also to a Training (UserInTraining)
- Registered Users can be in a Training (UserInTraining) which is part of an Event without being registered in the Event (UserInEvent)
- Unregistered Users can be in a Training (UserInTraining) which is part of an Event without being registered in the Event (UserInEvent)
- Unregistered Users can not be in a Event (UserInEvent) without being a registered User

Now my LINQ Expression should get all "Users" and "Unregistered Users" that are in "UsersInTraining" but not in "UserInEvent", and then return me a anonymous type (can also create a Model) that would look something like this:

> **UsersInTrainingButNotInEvent**
>
> Event Name
>
> Username
>
> IsUser (bool, false im not registered)
>
> Username (string,
>   NULL)

This was my expression (as far as i got):

```
from usr in _userService.GetAllUsers()
                join tr in _trainingService.GetAllTrainings() on usr.userID equals tr.userID into
                    usersInTraining
                join usrTr in _eventService.GetAllEvents() on usr.userID equals
                    usrTr.userID into usersInEvents
```

But from here on I dont know how to go on and do my logic in the LINQ Expression:

1. Get all Users in Trainings
2. Get all Users in Events
3. Get all registered Users that are in Training but not in Event and also Users that are not registered in "Users" but in Training
4. Return Anonymous type or a Model with the Details listed above

   I am also open for better strategys but I cannot change the Tables as these have to be so. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression lacks the `select` command, your LINQ doesn't know what to select from the buffer you created.
Try something like

```
var result = from usr in _userService.GetAllUsers()
                join tr in _trainingService.GetAllTrainings() on usr.userID equals tr.userID into
                    usersInTraining
                join usrTr in _eventService.GetAllEvents() on usr.userID equals
                    usrTr.userID into usersInEvents 
             select new { Username = usr.Username, EventName = usrTr.EventName /* Select other values here */ };
if(result.Any()) {
    for(int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++) {
        Debug.WriteLine("User: {0} / Event {1}", result[i].Username, result[i].EventName);
    }
}
```

What is inside "select new {}" is a creation of a new anonymous object instance, you can add anything you want and their type is implicitly known within C#, when you say "result.Username" it will automatically assume .Username as being the same type as User.Username. That is done in compile time, i believe.

Oh and yes, I almost forgot a quick link into [Join Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) reference, might be useful.

Comment: Thank you both solutions are great and made me understand it better. This one suits me better but both got a vote up!

Answer (score 1):

**Get all Users in Trainings**

```
var usersintraining = from c in UserInTraining
                select new
                {
          //Since you already have the FK relationship
          UserName = c.Users.Where(e => e.UserID)
                };
```

PS: you don't need `Username`  in `UserInTraining` , you already have it in the `Users` table

---

**Get all Users in Events**

```
var usersinevents = from c in UserInEvents
                select new
                {
          //Since you already have the FK relationship
          UserName = c.Users.Where(e => e.UserID)
                };
```